# Избыточно или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Грамотно ли писать дважды «сила» или стоит перестроить предложение: "Основной формой денег являются денежные знаки, наделенные в силу закона платежной силой".

Answer (score 1):

Стоит перестроить. Поскольку платежная сила - термин, а сила закона - переносный оборот (почти идиома), у убирать надо имеено последний. 
**Основной формой денег являются денежные знаки, наделённые законом платёжной силой.** - согласен. Можно, конечно, совсем переделать, но без контекста трудно сказать, на что именно автор хочет сделать смысловой акцент.
А повтора денег - денежные здесь нет. "Формами денег являются денежные знаки, электронные день и т.д.". Не знаю, насколько правильна само утверждение, но оно явно не несёт тавтологичности.

Answer (score 0):

На  мой взгляд, повтор здесь дважды: *в силу* закона - платежной *силой* (исправляю - по закону) и основной формой *денег* являются *денежные* знаки

Answer (score 0):

Наверно, *денег* и *денежные знаки* придётся оставить (таковы законы канцелярского языка). Предложение, по-моему, должно выглядеть так: **Основной формой денег являются денежные знаки, наделённые законом платёжной силой.**
Мда, но так *денежные знаки* в глаза ещё больше бросаются.(((